# Create category column based on data from another column

Tags: pandas, python-3.5

I have a python dataframe df as:

```
            Pkg  DateType
Date                     
2020-01-07  2.39 2020-01-07
2020-01-08  4.20 2020-01-09
2020-01-19  7.49 2020-02-01
2020-01-20  7.49 2020-03-01
```

I want the following:

```
            Pkg  DateType   DTCat
Date                     
2020-01-07  2.39 2020-01-07 NDay
2020-01-08  4.20 2020-01-01 BM 
2020-01-19  7.49 2020-02-01 NM
2020-01-20  7.49 2020-03-01 NP1M
```

where the column `DTCat` is created based on the following dictionary condition applied to column `DateType`

```
{'2020-01-07': 'NDay', '2020-01-01': 'BM', '2020-02-01': 'NM', '2020-03-01': 'NP1M'}
```

I am not sure how to apply the conditions to the column in the above dataframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just [map](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) it:

```
df['DTCat'] = df['DateType'].map({'2020-01-07': 'NDay', '2020-01-01': 'BM', '2020-02-01': 'NM', '2020-03-01': 'NP1M'})
```